# A geometric series weighted by a telescoping series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is is possible to get a closed form expression of the sum of the series shown below:
$$S_n = 1 + (a_1 - a_0)r + (a_2- a_1)r^2 + ... + (a_n - a_{n-1})r^n$$ where, $0 < a_0 < a_1 < ... < a_n$ and $0 < r<1$

Comment: Are $a_n$ terms of some geometric progression, or just any sequence in general?

Comment: No, they need not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very satisfying, but I suppose you could write:

$$\begin{align}
S_n & = 1 + (a_1 - a_0)r + (a_2- a_1)r^2 + \cdots + (a_n - a_{n-1})r^n \\
    & = 1 - a_0 r + a_1(r - r^2) + a_2(r^2 - r^3) + \cdots + a_{n-1}(r^{n-1} - r^n) + a_n r^n \\
    & = 1 - a_0 r + \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k (r^k - r^{k+1}) \right ) + a_n r^n \\
    & = 1 - a_0 r + (1 - r) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k r^k \right ) + a_n r^n
\end{align}$$

Without any real specification of $a_k$, I don't think you can get much further than this.

Incidentally, I wonder if maybe the definition of $S_n$ is supposed to start with $a_0 + \cdots$ rather than $1 + \cdots$? That would make more sense; currently, $a_0$ is a bit of a strange special case, handled differently from the other $a_k$.